# Do I need to implement hashCode() and equals() methods?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

If I have a map and an object as map key, are the default hash and equals methods enough?

```
class EventInfo{

    private String name;
    private Map<String, Integer> info
 }
```

Then I want to create a map:

```
Map<EventInfo, String> map = new HashMap<EventInfo, String>();
```

Do I have to explicitly implement hashCode() and equals()? Thanks.

Comment: The default equals and hashcode methods just use the address of the object.  You need explicit methods if you want two equivalent objects to compare equal (so that you can, eg, find an object you've inserted into a map).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you do. `HashMap`s work by computing the hash code of the key and using that as a base point. If the `hashCode` function isn't overriden (by you), then it will use the memory address, and `equals` will be the same as `==`.

If you're in Eclipse, it'll generate them for you. Click **Source** menu → **Generate hashCode() and equals()**.

If you don't have Eclipse, here's some that should work. (I generated these in Eclipse, as described above.)

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((info == null) ? 0 : info.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof EventInfo)) {
        return false;
    }
    EventInfo other = (EventInfo) obj;
    if (info == null) {
        if (other.info != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!info.equals(other.info)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I automatically generated in Eclipse. Cool! No any modifiation needed!

Comment: @user697911: I'm glad I could be of assistance. I notice that you've asked 20 questions, but haven't accepted any answers. If you find an answer that suits you, please consider clicking the green check mark (outlined) next to the answer, or at least giving it a nice upvote. You also get rep for accepting answers!

Comment: @user697911 you may also have to create an account to be able to accept answers; I'm not sure. I would recommend doing so anyway because it will advance your standing in the SO community, indicating that you are "here to stay" and not just asking one question and leaving. Plus, pretty much any username is better than `user697911` :)

Comment: You know, looking at this, I'm not sure the auto-generated equals() method is correct. What if `other` is a subclass of `EventInfo`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need them else you won't be able to compare two EventInfo (and your map won't work).

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, no.  The default implementations of hashCode() and equals() will produce results that *ought* to work.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

My understanding is that the default implementation of hashCode() works by taking the object's address in memory and converting to integer, and the default implementation of equals() returns true only if the two objects are actually the same object.

In practice, you could (and should) probably improve on both of those implementations.  For example, both methods should ignore object members that aren't important.  In addition, equals() might want to recursively compare references in the object.

In your particular case, you might define equals() as true if the two objects refer to the same string or the two strings are equal *and* the two maps are the same or they are equal.  I think WChargin gave you pretty good implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want to happen.  If two different `EventInfo` instances with the same `name` and `info` should result in two different keys, then you don't need to implement `equals` and `hashCode`.

So

```
EventInfo info1 = new EventInfo();
info1.setName("myname");
info1.setInfo(null);
EventInfo info2 = new EventInfo();
info2.setName("myname");
info2.setInfo(null);
```

`info1.equals(info2)` would return false and `info1.hashCode()` would return a different value to `info2.hashCode()`.

Therefore, when you are adding them to your map:

```
map.put(info1, "test1");
map.put(info2, "test2");
```

you would have two different entries.

Now, that may be desired behaviour.  For example, if your `EventInfo` is collecting different events, two distinct events with the same data may well want to be desired to be two different entries.

The `equals` and `hashCode` contracts is also applicable in a `Set`.

So for example, if your event info contains mouse clicks, it may well be desired that you would want to end up with:

```
Set<EventInfo> collectedEvents = new HashSet<EventInfo>();
collectedEvents.add(info1);
collectedEvents.add(info2);
```

2 collected events instead of just 1...

Hope I'm making sense here...

EDIT:

If however, the above set and map should only contain a single entry, then you could use apache commons [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) and [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) to simplify the implementation of `equals` and `hashCode`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof EventInfo) {
        EventInfo other = (EventInfo) obj;
        EqualsBuilder builder = new EqualsBuilder();
        builder.append(name, other.name);
        builder.append(info, other.info);
        return builder.isEquals();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    HashCodeBuilder builder = new HashCodeBuilder();
    builder.append(name);
    builder.append(info);
    return builder.toHashCode();
}
```

EDIT2:

It could also be appropriate if two `EventInfo` instances are considered the same, if they have the same name, for example if the `name` is some unique identifier (I know it's a bit far fetched with your specific object, but I'm generalising here...)